# how to get classes name in jquery after minification

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to glup a question came in my mind that for example i have a html css jquery like

```
<p class="myClass">
```

Css

```
.myClass{font-size:15px;}
```

Jquery

```
$('.myClass').html("Hello World");
```

Now if i minify my HTML AND CSS class name using **gulp selector** plugin it will become something like

```
<p class="a"> </p>
.a{font-size:15px;}
```

but the Jquery will remain same and the inner html part will generate error since the class name has been changed so my question is how to get all classes names exactly what glup selector has changed in jquery

Comment: this plugin is doing it see their exemples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-cssnames

Comment: let me test this plugin, i will let you know if it works

Comment: it works thank you for helping me out